# Dynamic programming: find all submatrix with highest cell number

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I have N*M matrix, for example

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I want to find all submatrixes by index, in which this index is the biggest.
For example: cell 1 has only submatrix 1, because it is the highest submatrix.

Cell 3 has submatrixes (1,2,3), (2,3) and 3

Cell 5 has submatrixes 5 and

```
1 2
4 5
```

Cell 6 can have submatrixes

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Another are for example

```
2 3
5 6
```

, or

```
3
6
```

Supposed difficulty of algorithm is O(N^3)

I tried to iterate matrix from (0,0) to (n,m), partitioning all possible submatrixes, but the problem is, that it doesn't iterate same submatrix more than 1 time.

Comment: You tagged this "dynamic programming", what principles or ideas or patterns of dynamic programming did you apply to your code?

Comment: Can't you just use two for loops for this?

Comment: If this is a pure algorithm question it is perhaps more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you trying to count them or print/return them?

Comment: Why doesn't cell 5 have submatrix 2,5 as well?